# How do I get my webpage to look like this?

Tags: html, css

I know, *this* isn't very specific, but it's hard to explain, so I'll provide images.
Here's how my webpage looks now:
[image: How it currently looks]

How do I use CSS to make it look like this?
[image: How I want it to look]

sorry if the image is pretty bad, I made it on paint.

Here's my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Dice Roll Game!</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CDNs -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- End of Bootstrap CDNs -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2> We're gonna roll a dice! <br><small>And you have to guess which number the dice will roll.</small></h2>
    <div>
 Select your guess:
 <select class="form-control" id="select">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
 </select>
</div>
    <button id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Roll!</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<h2> We're gonna roll a dice! <br><small>And you have to guess which number the dice will roll.</small></h2>
<div id="test-container">
    <p>Select your guess: </p>
    <select class="form-control" id="select">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Roll!</button>
```

CSS:

```
#test-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#test-container p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
#test-container select {
    width: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/et81qkzr/1/

Comment: @Anjunadeep Hey, could you accept this answer if it worked for you so the question is closed on SO? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `p` tag around the text "Select your guess:", and put a `div` tag around the text and the `select` tag.

```
<div>
 Select your guess:
 <select class="form-control" id="select">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

EDIT after comment:
If it's still the same, perhaps bootstrap is doing it's magic against your will. Try to match the Bootstrap guideline:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="select" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select your guess:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="select">
       <option>1</option>
       <option>2</option>
       <option>3</option>
       <option>4</option>
       <option>5</option>
       <option>6</option>
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <button id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Roll!</button>
   </div>
  </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: It's still the same mate :/